# How will find debian user password

Tags: debian

I have forgotten my user password into debian virtual environment (widows). How will reset my password?

Comment: Do you have root privileges?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to either bootstrap the OS, chroot the system and change the password then to try to reverse the password.

[See this article on howto chroot and password change](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/reset_a_forgotten_root_password_using_a_live_distribution.html)